# How to add a string value into a PHP array

Tags: php

When I add a string value into an array through `array_push()`, it gives me a numeric value, i.e.,

```
$array = array("one", "two", "three");
$array2 = array("test", "test2");
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if ($value === 'one') {
        $push = array_push($array2, $value);
    }
}
print_r($push);
```

Its output is `3`. I want `$array2 = array("test", "test2", "one")`

Comment: well, your code is working correctly...

Comment: yeah the code is working correctly but i need `one` should add at the end of an array and when i `print_r($push)` it should be like this `array [0]=>test,[1]=>test2,[2]=>one`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) is working as it is designed for.

It will add the value and returns the number of elements in that array.

so it is natural if it is returning 3 your array has 2 elements after array push there are now three elements.

You should `print_r($array2)` your array and look the elements.

Answer (score 8):

This line:

```
$push = array_push($array2, $value);
```

Should be just

```
array_push($array2, $value);
```

`array_push()` uses reference to the array for the first parameter. When you `print_r()`, you print the array `$array2`, instead of `$push`.

Answer (score 7):

You are printing the return value of `array_push` which is the number of items in the array after the push. Try this:

```
<?php

$array = array("one","two","three");
$array2 = array("test","test2");

foreach ($array as $value) {
    if ($value === 'one') {
       array_push($array2, $value);
    }
}

print_r($array2);
```

Answer (score 4):

Really, you should be using `$array2[] = $value;` which will put the value in the first available numeric key in the array, rather than `array_push()`.

To get the value of the last element in the array(i.e. what you just added) and keep the array intact, use `end($array)`, or to get the last element and remove it from array, use `array_pop($array)`

Answer (score 1):

array_push modifies $array2.
$push contains count($array2).

Check http://php.net/array_push.

Answer (score 1):

In more modern days you could add strings or other data types to an array with **Square Bracket method** like this:

```
$arr = ['hello'];
$arr[] = 'world';
```

This approach will add the string `'world'` to the `$arr` array variable.

Now the array will actually look like this `['hello', 'world']` which is pretty neat, and quicker than `array_push`

array_push would be more suitable if you were to push more than one element into the array.

Im pretty confident that **Square Bracket Method** was introduced in PHP 5.4

Answer (score 0):

array_push takes the array by reference and returns the new number of elements in the array, not the new array as described [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php). That is why you are getting 3. If you want to see the elements in the array use `printr($array2);`